# How to use this macro

Tags: ios, iphone

Hello everyone i have these defined in my .pch

```
#define HIDE_TABBAR
#define SHOW_TABBAR

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

And

```
#if IS_IPHONE_5
HIDE_TABBAR=568 
#else
HIDE_TABBAR=480 
#endif

#if IS_IPHONE_5
SHOW_TABBAR=519
#else
SHOW_TABBAR=431
#endif
```

Basically what i want to do is to check if screen is iphone 5 , and depending screen size set the define variables and use it in .m code. Can you tell me how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
const int HIDE_TABBAR = IS_IPHONE_5 ? 568 : 480;
const int SHOW_TABBAR = IS_IPHONE_5 ? 519 : 431;
```

or even:

```
const int HIDE_TABBAR = IS_IPHONE_5 ? 568 : 480;
const int SHOW_TABBAR = HIDE_TABBAR - 49;
```

If you really have to use macros for this (which is bad programming, but hey, it's your app):

```
#define HIDE_TABBAR (IS_IPHONE_5 ? 568 : 480)
#define SHOW_TABBAR (HIDE_TABBAR - 49)
```

Comment: hello thanks but this can't be written in prefix.pch, i have to add it in .m file? right?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
   if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
      // for iphone 5
    }
    else
    {
        // for non iphone 5
    }
```

EDIT: (wrt: avoid using if/else in my code) use [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Comment: Best to explain why the current code doesn't work

Comment: Hello i am want to use HIDE_TABBAR in .m instead. I am trying to avoid using if/else in my code ..

Comment: @veereef No if elses in your code? :P Are you mad?

Comment: i meant in my .m file IF(is_iphone5)

Comment: Don't you want it to change at run-time? Then you can have one App for both platforms?! I would make a helper class where I got all the system specific information at run-time.

Comment: Isn't this going to break anyway? surely these values change when you run  your application and there is a call in progress etc...